# Attempting to add "P" to itself on a elliptic curve, how should I do this?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

Ok, here is my curve: $y^2 = x^3 + 15$

I have a point, $P$ at $(-2.21, -2.051)$ and I want to get to $2 * P$,

There is an online calculator: (https://andrea.corbellini.name/ecc/interactive/reals-mul.html) and the calculator says $2 * P$ is $(17.178, 71.304)$

I can get the slope with: $\frac{3x^2 + A}{2y}$

and I can get $X$ with: $s^2 - 2x$

However, I'm unable to find $Y$, what should I do?

Comment: You have the line $y=m_1x+m_0$ with a known slope $m_1$. You know a point on the line, and can use that to determine $m_0$. Then you have a known $x$, and you need to find $y$. How might you accomplish that :-)

Comment: I already have X however? I just need help finding Y

Comment: Find $m_0$ first using the point you started with

Answer (score 1):

Your curve has distinct roots, so we can proceed in the most straighforward way. There is a subtlety that is important but easy to forget: The addition law for elliptic curves is given by $P_1+P_2 = P_3=(x_3,-y_3)$, where $(x_3,y_3)$ is the point on the curve where the line through $P_1$ and $P_2$ intersects the curve at a third point.

If $P = (x_1,y_1)$, $2P = P+P = (x_2,-y_2)$ then the line tangent at $P$ can be found to  have slope $m=f'(x_1)/2y_1$ (where $y^2 = f(x) = x^3+15$) by implicit differentiation. The line is then $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ so plugging in the $x$ value you obtained, say $x_2$, gives you a third point of intersection
\begin{align}
y_2 = \frac{f'(x_1)}{2y_1}(x_2-x_1)+y_1.
\end{align}
Then $2P = (x_2,-y_2).$

You can check out Koblitz's book cited below for more information, particularly section I.7 *The Addition Law.*

*Koblitz, Neal*, Introduction to elliptic curves and modular forms, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 97. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. viii, 248 pp. DM 112.00 (1993). [ZBL0553.10019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0553.10019).